# Flatpicker min days for range date

Tags: javascript, jquery, flatpickr

I want to add a minimal range of days when user pick a range date.I'm trying to do that by disable dates dynamically .

Lets say i want :

```
var minRangeDays = 6;
```

When user pick the first date , the 6 next days must be disabled to pick ? is it possible to do that ?

```
 flatick = $("#startDate").flatpickr({
    mode: "range",
    minDate: "today",
    enableTime: true,
    dateFormat: "H:i",
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "F j, Y at H:00",
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:00",
    disable: [
      function (date) {
        if (!minRangeDays) return true;
       // return false ;
      }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

This not possible in using `flatpickr` ,  because in your case , you want a range of date ,which mean result of an array with `begin` and `end` , thus no breaking date between the start and end ,

So by design in this plugin it's not possible to break a range in multiple disabled dates ,

By example , in the below snippet I've catch the  start date , in the `onchange` event, then tried to set a range check in the `disable` function as below snippet :

Conclusion won't work

See example snippet :

```js
$(function() {
  var minRangeDays = 6;
  
  let startDate = null; 
  
  flatick = $("#startDate").flatpickr({
    mode: "range",
    minDate: "today",
    enableTime: true,
    dateFormat: "H:i",
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "F j, Y at H:00",
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:00",
    onChange: [function(selectedDates){
       console.log(selectedDates)
       startDate = selectedDates[0] ? selectedDates[0] : null;
    }],
    disable: [
      function(date) {
         
        
        console.log(date.getDate() > startDate);
        if(startDate) {
          let endRange = new Date(startDate);
          endRange.setDate(endRange.getDate() + minRangeDays);
          console.log(date.getTime() > startDate.getTime() && date.getTime() < endRange.getTime())
          return (date > startDate && date < endRange); 
        }
        return false;
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.9/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.9/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
<input id="startDate" />
```