# Minimum data range in flatpickr

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I'm looking for a solution to add a minimum data range in flatpicks.js
For example, if the first selected date is 1 Sep the minimum next one selectable is 6 Sep.

I was thinking first of the "disable" option, but apparently, that will not work. ([Flatpicker min days for range date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66141038/flatpicker-min-days-for-range-date))

Any other solutions to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the Flatpickr `onChange` event.

In the `onChange` event we will then add 7 days to the second Flatpickr using `minDate: new Date(start_date).fp_incr(increase_number_of_days);`

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let start_date = $('#start_date');
  let end_date = $('#end_date');

  start_date.flatpickr({
    dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
    disableMobile: true,
    minDate: "today",
    onChange: function(selectedDates) {
      end_date.flatpickr({
        dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
        minDate: new Date(selectedDates).fp_incr(6), // add 7 days
      });
    }
  });

  end_date.flatpickr({});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.11/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.11/flatpickr.min.js"></script>

<input id="start_date" style="width:200px;">
<input id="end_date" style="width:200px;">
```

Comment: hi, your example is to add in day `fp_incr(6)`, how about if in subtract for hour or minutes?

Comment: @mastersuse You can then enter the value in minus e.g. `fp_incr(-6)`

Comment: Hi, i am using this as you advice, `minDate: new Date(selectedDates).fp_incr(-6)`, it is minus 6 days ago, not hour.